# How to read previous messages sent by bot in channel where it is administrator using c#?

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a bot who sends messages in my channel on regular basis.
I use below API for that in my C# code

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMessage?chat_id={1}&text={2}&parse_mode={3}
```

but now I also want to read previous messages sent by my bot in channel

Is there any API for same which can read previous messages sent by bot ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately the Bot API restricts reading messages sent by bots

**Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?**

Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this, we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots

Comment: i want to just read messages sent by same bot. Not other bot

Comment: @vaibhavshah i understand this. This use-case is not described in the telegram FAQ. Still, answer is same there. getUpdates method will not return messages sent by bots

Comment: But you always could log sent messages on the application side